# GNU Make: disable all built-in rules, except desired ones

Tags: gnu-make

Twice in the past, GNU make has destroyed my work because some of its built-in rules have `.c` files as a target.

If you have a file called `foo.c`, and also a `foo.l` Lex scanner or `foo.y` Yacc parser, watch out! GNU make assumes that the `.c` file is a target made from these (it's evidently a POSIX requirement!), and it will will do something like `mv y.tab.c foo.c` or `lex -t foo.l > foo.c`.

What is the way to disable all such hidden, dangerous rules (whether known or unknown) while keeping the useful ones?

Specifically, how can we give this request to GNU Make: "please retain all your rules related to (for example) .c and .o files, and disable all rules which involve any other file type"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Many of the predefined implicit rules are implemented in make as
>   suffix rules, so which ones will be defined depends on the *suffix list*...
>    If you modify the suffix list, the only predefined suffix rules in
>   effect will be those named by one or two of the suffixes that are on
>   the list you specify; rules whose suffixes fail to be on the list are
>   disabled...
>   If you wish to eliminate the default known suffixes instead of just
>   adding to them, write a rule for .SUFFIXES with no prerequisites. By
>   special dispensation, this eliminates all existing prerequisites of
>   .SUFFIXES. You can then write another rule to add the suffixes you
>   want.

```
.SUFFIXES:            # Delete the default suffixes
.SUFFIXES: .c .o      # Define a new suffix list
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I was already trying `SUFFIXES`, but I had only the second line `.SUFFIXES: .c .o` which adds to the set rather than replacing it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you can invoke _make_ with `-Rr` (you only really need one of those, but I usually forget which)